# LaTeX not finding my local files

Tags: filesystem-access, texinputs

I've tried following the advise in other postings here, but nothing is working and I'm now afraid I'm going to break something.

I've tried setting:

```
export TEXINPUTS=.:~/projects/ini/latex/texmf:$TEXINPUTS
```

I've tried running

```
sudo texhash ~/projects/ini/latx/texmf
```

But neither work.

The files I'm expecting LaTeX to find are

```
~/projects/ini/latex/texmf/tex/latex/stages/stages.tex
~/projects/ini/latex/texmf/tex/latex/choices/choices.tex
```

What am I not doing or doing wrong?

Comment: I don't have the variable `$TEXINPUTS`. What is it?

Comment: @sigur, I'm not entirely sure.  I was just trying to follow advice to similar questions posted here, but not succeeding.

Comment: You should put your first code in the file `.bashrc` on your home folder.

Comment: @sigur.  Yes.  That's were I put the `export...`

Comment: You're missing the trailing double slash for recursive searches: `.:~/projects/ini/latex/texmf//:` Don't add `$TEXINPUTS` which is nil in the environment; just a trailing colon stands for "add the usual value of the variable".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 ~/projects/ini/latex/texmf
```

will just look in that directory you want a path component of

```
~/projects/ini/latex/texmf//
```

to search subdirectories.

These days it is probably more common to set things in texmf.cnf configuration rather than use environment variables, although the same path syntax applies either way.

---

So on my TeXLive 2012 system I have:

```
$ kpsewhich texmf.cnf
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf.cnf
```

and that file looks like

```
$ more /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf.cnf
% (Public domain.)
% This texmf.cnf file should contain only your personal changes from the
% original texmf.cnf (for example, as chosen in the installer).
%
% That is, if you need to make changes to texmf.cnf, put your custom
% settings in this file, which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf.cnf, rather than
% the distributed file (which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf).
% And include *only* your changed values, not a copy of the whole thing!
%
```

If you look at the file it references in the web2c directory it is mostly comments just detailing all the things you can set. Note texmf.cnf files look a bit like shell environment settings but they are not they are read directly by the kpathsea library of TeX and work cross platforms including systems without a usable shell.

Comment: Do I just make a `texmf.cnf` file and put it in my home directory?

Comment: What other variables might be good to set and put in `texmf.cnf`

Comment: updated with example